# Populate Date and Time into Textview from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, timestamp, firebase-realtime-database

I created a listview with two textviews, i want to get the date and time specific to any data added to the database into the textview from firebase.

Is there any method to achieve the aforementioned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another child to store the timestamp when saving the data.

Your data structure should look something like this

```
"data": {
    "id1": {
        "text": "some text",
        "timestamp": 1472861629000
    },
    "id2": {
        "text": "some text",
        "timestamp": 1472861629000
    },
    "..."
}
```

To save the timestamp, you can pass a firebase constant `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` that will be converted to an epoch time based on firebase server time

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("text", "some text");
values.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
Database.ref().child("data").push().setValue(values);
```

To convert the epoch time to human readable date, use this method

```
public static String epochToFormatted(Long epoch) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
    return sdf.format(new Date(epoch));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wilik, Let me give it a try, i will get back to you soonest.

Comment: sure @KennyDabiri, let me know if you have problems